# Sorting Excel sheet based on names

Tags: excel-2007

I have an Excel sheet which contains of name, address, and contact number etc. Below is how my Excel sheet looks like:

```
1. murali
   H.No:xxx
   xxxx street
   xxxx nagar
   xxxx layout delhi
   contact no:xxxx

2. bali
   H.No:yyy
   yyyy nagar
   lucknow
   contact no:yyyy

3. lali
   H.No:zzzz
   zzzz complex
   zzzz street
   besides zzzz
   zzzz nagar
   assam
   contact no:zzzz
```

How can I sort it based on the names while my address and the rest of the details remain unchanged respectively.

Comment: This kind of data layout is not ideal for any kind of manipulation. You'd be much better off if you created a table with a column for each piece of information. Some cells will stay empty in some rows, but you can then easily sort by any field, name, or city, for example. Instead of creating a solution to sort the messy data above, you may be better off with a solution that creates a proper data table. Any effort will involve VBA.

Comment: Your sample is not clear, is 1,2,3 on a separate column than the name and address rows? or are they row numbers? Are your names addresses on the same cell? Take a screenshot of your data and insert to your question.

Comment: @perror, what makes you think that the data is laid out like that? This is an assumption that cannot be substantiated by the original text monu posted. Your edit does not help.

Comment: I used the text to rebuild it. It says that columns are: `name` `address` and `contact number` (and others...). I assumed it was like this... Anyway, they layout of the spreadsheet has very few impact on the answer because he just want to keep the rest of the line unchanged (at least, this is what I deduced from what was written but I might be wrong...).

Comment: @perror You may want to hold back on the editing a bit. You currently have over 80 edits compared to 32 answers. Sure, a badge is nice, but don't force it, by editing the meaning out of questions. Make sure you really understand what you are editing. If you don't understand what you're dealing with, just move on to the next question.

Comment: @teylyn: You may want to ask a few more questions... Please, don't tell me how to behave. I was wrong for this edit. But, it was one over 80. I do care about understanding before modifying. Here, I just misunderstood the question, it happens and will happen from time to time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[edit]: Wow, the layout after the edit by [perror](https://stackoverflow.com/users/717822/perror) changed the scope of the question completely.

Just make sure there is a header row with column titles. Then turn on Autofilter and sort by the name column.

[end of edit]

An approach without VBA:

Make sure row 1 is empty. Data starts in row 2. From your example above it looks as if the number is in a different column. In my example, the number is in column A, the data in column B. Enter this formula into cell C2 and copy down to the last row of data:

```
=IF(B1="",LEFT(B2,1)&TEXT(LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2&".")-1),"00000"),C1)
```

I have added another data set with the name "murali" for illustration purposes, so there are two names that start with murali.

[image]

Now copy column C and paste it back into column C using Paste Special > Values.

Add column headers into cells A1 to C1, then fire up the autofilter with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> or the ribbon command and sort A to Z by column C.

The result is:

[image]

Now you can delete column C.

Comment: Wow... I must admit I didn't think about such a layout... You are probably right. Please revert my edit.

Comment: thanks @teylyn you have figured my problem exactly and the solution is what I needed.... you are really amazing....thanks a lot